# How to get nth to n+ath bytes across all rows form a text file in *nix?

Tags: text-processing, awk, head

I have a large text file (>200MB). I want to read [n, n+a] bytes across all rows.

Suppose there are 1000 rows in the original text file. The output file would be 1000 rows.

What I know `head -c349 original.text|tail -c28 > output.txt`. However, this only outputs one row. How can I `iterate` though all rows?

Example:
n = 2 a = 1.

Input: `123456
      789789`

Output: `23
       89`

Comment: What do you mean with `[n, n+a] bytes`? The `a+1` bytes starting at position `n` on each line? A short sample input and output would help immensely.

Comment: @ilkkachu An example has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cut command will do it. For example, `cut -c 10-12` will print
characters 10 to 12 (inclusive) from each line of its input.

You can write `cut -b 10-12` instead if you really mean bytes rather
than characters.

Comment: Simple & elegant.